# Encoding JSON Through PHP

Tags: php, json

Ok so I am trying to make a loop in php for json but I dont know what or how to loop it where I can keep the format I want for the JSON output. This is what i have:

```
$number = array(31,25,160);
$json_holder = array();
$counter = count($names);
$i = 0;

while($i < $counter){
    $json_holder = array('user'=> array('results'=> array('tagnumber' => $number[$i],'status'=>'good'),);
    echo json_encode($json_holder);
    $i++;
}
```

And my output:

```
{"user":{"results":{"tagnumber":31,"status":"good"}}}  
{"user":{"results":{"tagnumber":25,"status":"good"}}}  
{"user":{"results":{"tagnumber":160,"status":"good"}}}
```

So instead of making new JSON root elements everytime I want to just make a new array in results so it would output like:

```
{
    "user": {
        "results": [{
            "tagnumber": 31,
        } {
            "tagnumber": 25,
        } {
            "tagnumber": 160,
        }],
        "status": "okay"
    }
}
```

I hope I am making sense

Comment: How does your `while` loop not infinite loop without an `$i++`?

Comment: The format your would like isn't a very good one. What if different objects have different statuses? Usually, having an object with just one property indicates bad design.

Comment: Im sorry, I forgot to paste that part in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
$number = array(31,25,160);
$payload = array('user' => array('results' => array(), 'status' => 'okay'));
foreach ($number as $num) {
   $payload['user']['results'][]['tagnumber'] = $num;
}
echo json_encode($payload);
```

No need for a `for()` loop here.

**Output**

```
{
    "user": {
        "results": [
            {
                "tagnumber": 31
            },
            {
                "tagnumber": 25
            },
            {
                "tagnumber": 160
            }
        ],
        "status": "okay"
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it'd be better to attach the `status` to each individual `tagnumber` group than to only have one for the entire `user`.

Comment: Well that's not what he/she requested.

Comment: @mc10: You are completely right but I am just starting to learn JSON and its concepts as this was something I needed to help put the piece to a puzzle together.

Comment: @David Great. A lot of clarity was provided with that answer. I dont know why I was so bent on using a for loop instead of a foreach. I can see how to structure this better now

Comment: It just makes it easier. Learning how to manipulate `array()`s comes with time, and once you master them, it makes things like this a lot easier to work on.